# How to run excel macro using NPOI

Tags: npoi

I have to run excel macro using npoi in c sharp. i dont know how to do it in code behid. Please let me know how to fix this one.

Thanks

Comment: This question is off topic. It has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Can you add more details to the question.

Comment: hi clijsters, kumar chandraketu thank you for your reply. I want run macro excel programmatically i need to use microsoft office interop services. but its paid one. i need to run this macro excel file through npoi dll reference. is that possible or not?